# Coinbase Python API - Having trouble changing currency (EUR / LTC)

Tags: python, coinbase-api

I'm probably missing something very stupid but I'm having trouble changing currencies in the client.get_exchange_rates() and get_spot_price() methods

As defined here, 
https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2?python#exchange-rates

it's supposed to be as simple as :

```
rates_BTC = client.get_exchange_rates(currency='BTC')
print(rates_BTC)
```

but it always return in USD

```
{
  "currency": "USD",
  "rates": {
    "AED": "3.67",
    "AFN": "68.66",
    "ALL": "111.94",
...
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Interesting. What do you get from `currencies = client.get_currencies()` is BTC in that response? I'm wondering if they recently renamed (can't see why) for some kind of differentiation. USD is the default response so I guess it doesn't like what you queried for.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. 
The get_currencies seems legit and BTC is indeed present... 
   {
      "id": "BTC",
      "min_size": "0.00000001",
      "name": "Bitcoin"
    },

Comment: You might have to contact them about this. There's no authentication required for this query and I don't see anything wrong with your attempt (seems identical to the docs) so I can't think of any reason for this.

Comment: Assuming version 3 of python, can you `from http.client import HTTPConnection; HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1` and run the command again and post the URL. It looks like the `currency` param is not being added to the url because `USD` is default. This will show if it is client problem or a server problem.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Has that really not been solved during the last 1 year and 7 months?